# regex - вставка тега в HTML код

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

у меня вот такая задача:

> Требуется вставить после тега `<body>` строку `<h1>Hello</h1>`

```
входная строка: <html> <body style="height: 200px"> </body> </html>
```

пытаюсь использовать опережающие и ретроспективные проверки:

```
std::string input("<html> <body style=\"height: 200px\"> </body> </html>");
std::regex myreg("((?<=body>).*(?=<\/body>))");
std::cout << regex_replace(input, myreg, "<h1>Hello</h1>$0");
```

в чем здесь проблема?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Требуется вставить после тега `<body>` строку `<h1>Hello</h1>`

Не `c++` конечно... Но регулярки вроде схожи. Предложу такой вариант...

```js
let str = '<html> <body style="height: 200px"> </body> </html>'
const re = /(?<=\<body.*?>)(.)/i
str = str.replace(re, '<h1>Hello</h1>$1')
console.log(str)
```